# The view cube does not show up on the IPad

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Is there a reason why the view cube doesn't show up in the viewer on an iPad?

For example, this test site doesn't show the view cube:
https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/database?id=583ec7efebfb320e3cef26a5

Comment: What’s the iPad model? And browser (Safari/Chrome/other)?

Comment: This is on an iPad Pro running Safari

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
viewer.createViewCube();
viewer.displayViewCube(true);
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: We can call the above lines and the view cube will display. Is the behavior intentional on the iPad?  Every other browser shows the view cube by default.

Comment: yes it is intended, it is not on by default for mobile devices, screens are smaller so displaying it will make the model not be the main thing on the screen. Glad it worked.

Comment: We've tried the above code in the event OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT but see the view cube display briefly, the get hidden.  Do you know WHEN the cube is removed in the viewer initialization?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show the view cube is to set the setting:

```
localStorage.setItem(
  'Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D.SavedSettings.viewCube',
  true
);
```

Just be conscious that this will override user settings, so you should also act to see if the user explicitly set the view cube to hidden and respect that setting.